# Javascript Splash Screen + Media Query

Tags: javascript, html, css, splash-screen

I'm using js for a splashscreen with a video background. If anyone clicks on it, it fades into the home page. For mobile screens, I want to add an image that shows instead of the video. My initial attempt showed the image, but it wouldn't fade out after I clicked on it. Here's my code before my attempt:

```
<style>
 #splashscreen {  
    background-color: #000000;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20000;
}


 .logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index:100000;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 55%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    max-width:90%;
  }

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 10000;
}
</style>


<div id="splashscreen">

  <a href="#" class="enter_link">
    <img class="logo" src="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <video playsinline=""  autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="XXXXXXXXXXX" id="bgvid">
  <source src="XXXXXXXXXXX" type="video/mp4">
</source></video></a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

    $(window).load(function(){

$('.enter_link').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('#splashscreen').fadeOut(500);
});

    });

  //]]>
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: create a snippet please to have a look

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ovfqgsp8/  When the screen is less than 600px, the video stops showing and the black background image appears. I want to be able to click anywhere and have it fade out. Currently, I have to click directly on the logo for that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a fiddle which solves your issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".enter_link").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this)
      .parent("#splashscreen")
      .fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
  #splashscreen {
  background-color: #000000;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20000;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100000;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 55%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    max-width: 90%;
  }
  video {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 10000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="splashscreen">

  <a href="#" class="enter_link">
    <img class="logo" src="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <video playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="XXXXXXXXXXX" id="bgvid">
      <source src="XXXXXXXXXXX" type="video/mp4">
      </source>
    </video>
  </a>
</div>
```

The changes I've made are,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".enter_link").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this)
      .parent("#splashscreen")
      .fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

Your anchor tag doesn't cover the whole page though, instead you could have the `click` event directly on `#splashscreen` and do the following in your method,

```
$(this).fadeOut(500);
```

**UPDATE**

To track first visit to the site, you can use `localStorage` - you can set a flag called `firstVisit`

```
let firstVisit = !localStorage.getItem('firstVisitCompleted')
if (firstVisit) {
  showSplashScreen()
  localStorage.setItem('firstVisitCompleted', true)
} else {
  hideSplashScreen()
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. However, it looks like it's still not working. Check out this fiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/ovfqgsp8/   When the video is showing, I can click on it and it fades out. When the screen is less than 600px, I've disabled the video and replaced it with black.png but I can't click anywhere to fade out. I have to click directly on the logo.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. One more question. Do you know how I would make that splash screen only show after the first visit to the site?

Comment: @championofthesun It "wasn't working" because the anchor tag from your code was not visible since I didn't have the image.

Regarding your other question, you can use localStorage to track first visit to the site. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help as I'm total novice when it comes to  javascript. For the firstVisit code you gave me, do I add that directly to the splash screen code like this? `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".enter_link").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this)
      .parent("#splashscreen")
      .fadeOut(500);
  });
  let firstVisit = !localStorage.getItem('firstVisitCompleted')
if (firstVisit) {
  showSplashScreen()
  localStorage.setItem('firstVisitCompleted', true)
} else {
  hideSplashScreen()
}
});`

Comment: @championofthesun You want the splash screen to be shown only when a user first visits the site, correct?

Comment: yeah that is what I was hoping to do

Comment: @championofthesun You'll need to define 2 functions for showing and hiding the splash screen - similar to what I've done in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0egocjLa/

Basically your anchor tag was missing height. Provide an height and click function will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".enter_link").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this)
      .parent("#splashscreen")
      .fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
#splashscreen {
  background-color: #000000;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20000;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100000;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 55%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    max-width: 90%;
  }
  video {
    display: none;
  }
  a{
    display:block;
    height:100vh;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="splashscreen">

  <a href="#" class="enter_link">
    <img class="logo" src="https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/logo-so-white.png">
    <video playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2999/0620/files/black-bg.png" id="bgvid">
      <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </source>
    </video>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh nice! Thank you. One more thing, do you know how I could make that splash screen only appear on the first visit to the site?

Comment: Use localstorage concept in HTML5 : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp